# Using Java with Matlab: passing Class type as a method argument

Tags: java, matlab, class, generic-type-argument

I am using a java public interface in a matlab scripted (but object oriented) software.

We frequently have to call java methods and this work flawlessly. If I have the following java class:

```
package com.toto

public class Foo {
    public static void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Hello World"); 
    }
}
```

Then in Matlab I just call:

```
com.toto.Foo.printHello
```

To get the print displayed in my console command.

Now what I would like to do is something similar to:

```
package com.toto

public class Foo {
    public static <E> void printClass(Class<E> type) {
        System.out.println("My type: " + type); 
    }
}

public class Goo {
....
}
```

And in Matlab:

```
com.toto.Foo.printClass(com.toto.Goo.class)
```

Which is actually not working.

Any solution for this ?

Edit: here is a working java example, the code in main should be executed under matlab:

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Foo.printClass(Goo.class);
  }
}

public class Foo 
{
    public static <E> void printClass(Class<E> type) 
    {
        System.out.println("My type: " + type); 
    }
}

 public class Goo {
    public Goo() {};
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `.class` syntax is not valid in Matlab:

```
com.toto.Goo.class
```

What you can do is to make an instance of `Goo` and then use the [getClass](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method on that object:

```
goo = com.toto.Goo();
com.toto.Foo.printClass(goo.getClass());
```

Or if you want to use only the name of the Java class (or for example in case of Java `enum`s where the instantiation is not possible) you can use [`javaclass`](http://www.undocumentedmatlab.com/files/javaclass.m) from [undocumentedmatlab.com](http://www.undocumentedmatlab.com).

The main part of this function is

```
jclass = java.lang.Class.forName('com.toto.Goo', ...
    true, ...
    java.lang.Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

which uses the [forName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29) method of `Class`:

> Returns the Class object associated with the class or interface with
>   the given string name, using the given class loader.

This second approach can be used as an equivalent of the Java `.class` syntax.

Comment: That's actually what I am doing. I have a static getDefault() method because Goo is actually an Enum, so I can't have a public constructor in it.

However, of course I am on java 1.6 so I cannot enforce the getDefault() method in a interface, nor an abstract class. So I basically rely on the developer good will to implement this method.

This is why I dislike this solution (and that I really do not like java, on the side).

Comment: Updated the answer for you. I hope it satisfies your needs.

Comment: That's great thanks, Mathworks discourage the use of forName (they indicate to use javaObjectEDT), but in that case it's a really nice use